# Error in email attached file as file gets corrupted at receiver side

Tags: php

I am trying to send Email with Attachment using php.
Attachment is sent but attachment data gets corrupted at receiver side.
File size is appropriately received at receiver side then also file gets corrupted
Please help me

My Code

```
<?php
    ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
    include "phpmailer/class.smtp.php";
    include "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";

    $Host = "mail.gmail.com";                       // SMTP servers
    $Username = "*******@gmail.com";    // SMTP password
    $Password = "******";                   // SMTP username

    $From = "*****@gmail.com";
    $FromName = "from";


    $str =$_SESSION['MailAll'];

$arr=explode(",",$str);

print_r ($arr);





    $Tos=$arr;  
//  $Tos=json_encode($Tos);
    $Ccs = array(
        "CC Name 1" => "cc-email-1@yahoo.com",
        "CC Name 2" => "cc-email-2@gmail.com"
    );

    $Subject ="Project Abstract";
    $Body =$_POST['mailcont'] ;;

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();                    // send via SMTP
    $mail->Host     = $Host; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;             // turn on SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = $Username;  
    $mail->Password = $Password; 

    $mail->From     = $From;
    $mail->FromName = $FromName;
    foreach($Tos as $key => $val){
        $mail->AddAddress($val , $key); 
    }

    //foreach($Ccs as $key => $val){
        //$mail->AddCC($val , $key); 
    //}

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;               // set word wrap
    $mail->Priority = 1; 
    $mail->IsHTML(true); 
/////attachment
    $str=trim($_SESSION['DOCFILE']);//eg-"Time Table Generator.docx","one_size_does_not_fir_all.pdf"

    $arr=explode(",",$str);


  for($i=0;$i<count($arr)-1;$i++){
     $mail->AddAttachment($arr[$i]);
    echo 'array size '.$arr[$i];
}




    $mail->Subject  =  $Subject;
    $mail->Body     =  $Body;




    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else
    {
    //  header('location:../sendABS.php');
      echo 'Message has been sent.';
    }

?>
```

Comment: It sends ok? Why and/or how does it get corrupted? What makes you think it is corrupted?

Comment: Does DOCFILE have those quotes you mentioned?? try trimming them off first.

Comment: At receiver side when i am trying to open that file after downloading an error message dialogue box get pops up displaying message error exists in this page. please contact the person who have created this

Comment: -Waygood I have trimmed DOCFILE you can check it in my code

Comment: do those files also have paths??? or are they in the same folder as PHPMailer or your script? try using file_exists();

Comment: you trimmed DOCFILE but not $arr[$i], DOCFILE has quotes in the middle of it.

Comment: -Waygood Instead of usinf DOCFILE I write there hardcoded file name.but still same problem

Comment: with a path to file? ./ = current directory

Comment: I have trim this $arr[$i] Also still not working

Comment: Actually My php file is in same directory where I store all document.and from database I retentive file name .and save it in $_session['DOCFILE']

Comment: -Gerald Versluis do you have any idea?

Comment: -Waygood thanks for helping me.. i got the solution actually I timed the string before assigning it to session.. after removing that it worked